# Class "keyword arguments" in Python 3

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I noticed this from the docstring of `__build_class__`:

```
__build_class__(func, name, *bases, metaclass=None, **kwds) -> class

Internal helper function used by the class statement.
```

The part that intrigued me was the `**kwds` part. Can class definitions take keyword arguments? I tried it, but I got a very strange error:

```
>>> class Test(a=1):
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

What's the deal here? Can classes in Python 3 somehow accept keyword arguments? Maybe a special metaclass is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can classes in Python 3 somehow accept keyword arguments?

Yes. Any keyword arguments in the `class` statement besides `metaclass` are passed to the metaclass. If the `metaclass` argument is specified, it's used as the metaclass; otherwise, the metaclass is `type`. See [PEP 3115](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) for more details.

Comment: I see. Assumedly this was just implemented for the sake of the new `metaclass=` syntax, since I think the same thing should be possible by just using a metaclass factory, like `class MyClass(metaclass=get_metaclass(**kwargs))`.